# Maxwell Boltzmann distribution: Going from momentum to energy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics

I am learning about the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution, and am trying to convert the equation from momentum into energy, but I'm stuck on changing $d^n p$ into $dE$. I have the equation:
$$
E=\frac{|\textbf{p}|^2}{2m}
$$
And when I looked on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution#Distribution_for_the_energy), I see that whoever wrote it changed it as:
$$
d^3 \textbf{p} = 4\pi |\textbf{p}|^2d|\textbf{p}|= 4\pi m\sqrt{2mE}dE
$$
I understand how $4\pi |\textbf{p}|^2d|\textbf{p}|= 4\pi m\sqrt{2mE}dE$,
but I don't understand how they got:
$$
d^3 p = 4\pi |\textbf{p}|^2d|\textbf{p}|
$$
Is there a certain identity or something that I need to make use of? Also how doe this vary for different dimensions?
Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to solve this please?

Comment: I don't know very much about this field but this reminds of saying $d^3\textbf{x}=4\pi |\textbf{x}|^2d|\textbf{x}|=4\pi r^2 dr$ in position space, when you assume spherical symmetry. This looks like the same thing but in momentum space

Comment: @rbncruise - Note that the $d^{3}p \rightarrow 4\pi \ p^{2} \ dp$ approximation only works if the distribution is one-dimensional (i.e., if there is spherical symmetry as _tmwilson26_ pointed out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the assumption here is spherical symmetry, and what they've done is integrate over the angular coordinates.  So what they say is:

$$d^3p = p^2\sin(\theta_p)d\theta_p d\phi_p dp$$

$$\int_{\theta,\phi}d^3p = \int_{\theta,\phi}p^2\sin(\theta_p)d\theta_p d\phi_p dp$$

Integrating over the angular coordinates gives $4\pi p^2 dp$

Comment: I see, and do you know how to  perform this for an arbitrary number of dimensions $d^n \textbf{p} $?

Comment: @rbncruise See this section of the wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_element